# A question about the proof of an obvious result

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

This is obviously true that a local homeomorphism is a continuous map. I tried to prove it this way :

Suppose $f:X \to Y$ is a local homeomorphism, then $f$ is continuous if for each $x\in X$ and each neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ we can find a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U) \subset V$.

Since $f$ is a local homeo , $x$ has a neighborhood $U$ which is homeomorphic to $W=f(U)$, such that $W$ is open in $Y$. Claim is that the required neighborhood of $x$ is  $f^{-1}(W \cap V)$. $f^{-1}(W \cap V)$ is open , since $f|_U:U \to W$ is a homeo, and obviously $f(f^{-1}(W \cap V)) \subset V$.

I was wondering if there is an easier way to show this result, thank you in advance

Comment: Since $f$ is a local homeomorphism, $x$ has a neighborhood $U$ which is homeomorphic to $W=f(U)$, not some arbitrary $W$.

Comment: Thanks ! I meant the same thing though, I'll fix it

Comment: And, according to the definition of local homeomorphism on Wikipedia, so that $f(U)$ is open in $Y$...

Comment: What do you mean ? I have mentioned that $f(U)$ is open !

Comment: Yeah, mostly quibbling with the language. "... the open set $W=f(U)$" is different from "... such that $W=f(U)$ is open." One implies that you think you know $f(U)$ is open no matter what, the other implies that it is a result of the definition.

Comment: I see ! Thank you so much for this remark ! will fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear how you could write a simpler proof. Basically, you are using each feature of the "local homeomorphism" exactly once:

1. $f(U)$ being open in $Y$ means $f(U)\cap V$ is an open subset of $f(U)$.
2. $f$ being a homeomorphism $U\to f(U)$ means that $f^{-1}$ of an open subset of $f(U)$ is an open subset of $U$, and hence an open subset of $X$.